# Bad encoding with urxvt and prezto on Arch

Tags: unicode, utf-8, archlinux, prezto

I'm using Arch Linux with urxvt-unicode and when I execute a command to test if [my terminal is compatible with Prezto](https://gist.github.com/agnoster/3712874#compatibility), it's missing some characters:

[image]

My locale is as following:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum, following *Python 3.5.1* script shows that some characters are [`Co` Unicode category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) i.e. *Other, Private Use*. Hence, your app should use a **font** containing such *private* characters to render them properly.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>>
>>> for char in u'\ue0b0',u'\u00b1',u'\ue0a0',u'\u27a6',u'\u2718',u'\u26a1',u'\u2699':
...     print (char, unicodedata.category(char), unicodedata.name(char,'private use'))
...
 Co private use
± Sm PLUS-MINUS SIGN
 Co private use
➦ So HEAVY BLACK CURVED UPWARDS AND RIGHTWARDS ARROW
✘ So HEAVY BALLOT X
⚡ So HIGH VOLTAGE SIGN
⚙ So GEAR
>>>
```

Compare results of similar *PowerShell* script:

```
> 0xe0b0,0x00b1,0xe0a0,0x27a6,0x2718,0x26a1,0x2699 | Get-CharInfo | Format-Table -AutoSize

Char CodePoint    Category Description                                    
---- ---------    -------- -----------                                    
    U+E0B0     PrivateUse Private Use                                    
   ± U+00B1     MathSymbol Plus-Minus Sign                                
    U+E0A0     PrivateUse Private Use                                    
   ➦ U+27A6    OtherSymbol Heavy Black Curved Upwards And Rightwards Arrow
   ✘ U+2718    OtherSymbol Heavy Ballot X                                 
   ⚡ U+26A1    OtherSymbol High Voltage Sign                              
   ⚙ U+2699    OtherSymbol Gear
```